# I want my missing data take mean value of my missing data

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

[image]

I have copied exact code but it is not giving me desired output results, I want my missing data to get resolved by the code i typed but it dont

Comment: Please add your code as text, people will be more likely to help

Comment: Please provide code as text. Probably you just should install `scipy`: `pip install scipy`

Comment: oh i figure this out
thanks